# Context menu not fully visible if to point from below of the page

Tags: javascript, css, stenciljs

Context menu goes down, when point from down, it is not fully visible, how can I make to be fully visible at bottom of page by CSS

CSS
[image]

Screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution for this is to dynamically adjust the position of the element so that it does not extend outside the window. You appear to already be setting the position via `top` and `left` so you probably only need to modify your calculation to incorporate the window limits.